# How to display exact modified date/time in finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I want to display the exact modified date/time in Finder. How can I do this?

As you may know, it's displaying things like like "yesterday" or "today" or just a date. I want to see the time component too as that can be important in some situations.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Finder - View > Show View Options or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>

Uncheck "use relative dates"

Comment: That _option_ doesn't exist in OS X 10.8.x, do you know of a way?  Maybe a `defaults write` command?

Comment: Sorry, no idea on 10.8 - you should put the OS in the question, to avoid guesswork [if it was your question, otherwise raise another, with specific info.]

Comment: This does not show seconds.